# How to configure end of trials

Tags: stripe-payments

My use-case is that whenever I have a trial subscription, once the trial ends and the user has no payment method on stripe, I simply want to cancel the subscription instead of generating an invoice. Is there a way to configure this on Stripe or would it need an external task to run each day and do this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new invoice will always be generated when a payment is due, and Stripe will try to charge the customer for it. If you want to avoid it, you will need to check if the customer has a PaymentMethod on the last day of the trial, and update the Subscription to set the `cancel_at_period_end` [property](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update?lang=curl#update_subscription-cancel_at_period_end) to true.

Alternatively, you can listen to [customer.subscription.updated](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-customer.subscription.updated) webhook event - when the status changes from `trialing` to `active` and the customer does not have a PaymentMethod, you can [cancel the Subscription manually](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/cancel). In this case, however, a draft Invoice will still be created, but automatic collection will be stopped - the invoice will stay as a draft and will never be finalized.